# ASP.NET Core Load an Onnx file inside a Docker container

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I am trying to build an ASP.NET Core api that uses an Onnx machine learning model file. I load it in like this:

```
OnnxScoringEstimator pipeline = _mlContext.Transforms.ApplyOnnxModel(_config.GetSection("ModelPath").Value);
```

This means it takes the path from the appsettings.json file, which looks like this:

appsettings.Development.json

```
"ModelPath": "C:\\Users\\name\\dev\\solution\\project\\model.onnx"
```

and por my appsettings.Production.json

```
"ModelPath": "./model.onnx"
```

It does work when debugging the project on my machine but not when I build it in a docker container. Then it gives the following error:

```
Connection id "0HLV880PG88DT", Request id "0HLV880PG88DT:00000002": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.

System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'onnxruntime' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: libonnxruntime: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Because it says `No such file or directory` I would say it has something to do with my path to the model being wrong but im not sure.

I hope someone can help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this as well and after a lot of head-scratching I came across a solution that worked for me in a Github issue that pointed to the ONNX Runtime System Requirements docs: https://github.com/Microsoft/onnxruntime#system-requirements

The key point:

> For Linux, the system must have libgomp.so.1 which can be installed using apt-get install libgomp1.

Once I added the following command to my Dockerfile, my app worked as expected:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libgomp1
```